# Configuring multiple FastEthernet interfaces using GNS3

Tags: cisco, ospf

I'm doing a lab for my internetworking course and I'm using GNS3 as the emulator. I can configure single FastEthernet interfaces on each router but I need to have two per router. I am using the c7200 image and router.

This is my attempt to configure the router.

Router>enable
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#interface f0/0
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.192
Router(config-if)#no shutdown
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface f0/1
                            ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Router(config)#

Every time I try to do the f0/1 interface I get the invalid input detected message.

WHY?!!?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the interface FastEthernet0/1 does not exist ?

Use the command `Router#show ip interface brief`, to verify that the interface exists.

If it doesn't exist, in GNS3 you can add additional interfaces through the *configure* option menu of the router(*slots* tab).

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.
right click on router, click on configure, go to slots, click on slot 0, choose the second on (2FE).
apply, and ok, now u have 2 FastEthernet interfaces.